# What is the relationship between sampleRate and various Google Analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We have a high-volume site that is exceeding the Google Analytics hit quota. As a solution, we were planning on limiting the sample rate (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sampleRate) to around 5%.

Before we do this, I'd like to understand what setting a sample rate does to GA reports like pageview or events. Will those reports show only 5% of overall hits? Or will they be adjusted to account for the sample rate?

As a toy example, if our site had 100 users and we set sampleRate = 5, we'd expect only 5 users data to get tracked. Now imagine those 5 users each visited exactly 1 page and generated 1 pageview. When you view the pageview report, would that report show 5 pageviews (only the sample), or would it show 100 pageviews (reflecting the true user pageview estimate)? Or asked differently, once I set sampleRate = 5, do I now need to multiply all count metrics x 20 to estimate overall site usage, or will GA reports do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

The reports will only see around 5% of the hits. You will need to multiply your results by 20 when looking at absolute numbers. GA won't multiply for you.